# Error connecting ScyllaDB in Docker from Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, docker, cassandra, scylla

I hope someone can help me with this issues, as I'm no expert with docker.

I have a Java Spring Boot application (let's call it my-app) that uses ScyllaDB. So far, I have been running the application with Spring Boot embedded Apache Tomcat build, and the database is running in Docker with no issues.

Here is the docker-compose file for the 3 Scylla nodes:

```
version: "3"

services:

  scylla-node1:
    container_name: scylla-node1
    image: scylladb/scylla:4.5.0
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scylla-node1,scylla-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 9042:9042
    volumes:
      - "./scylla/scylla.yaml:/etc/scylla/scylla.yaml"
      - "./scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties.dc1:/etc/scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties"
    networks:
      - scylla-network

  scylla-node2:
    container_name: scylla-node2
    image: scylladb/scylla:4.5.0
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scylla-node1,scylla-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 9043:9042
    volumes:
      - "./scylla/scylla.yaml:/etc/scylla/scylla.yaml"
      - "./scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties.dc1:/etc/scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties"
    networks:
      - scylla-network

  scylla-node3:
    container_name: scylla-node3
    image: scylladb/scylla:4.5.0
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scylla-node1,scylla-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 9044:9042
    volumes:
      - "./scylla/scylla.yaml:/etc/scylla/scylla.yaml"
      - "./scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties.dc1:/etc/scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties"
    networks:
      - scylla-network
```

Using the node tool, I can see the DB is fine:

```
Datacenter: DC1
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.27.0.3  202.92 KB  256          ?       4e2690ec-393b-426d-8956-fb775ab5b3f9  Rack1
UN  172.27.0.2  99.5 KB    256          ?       ae6a0b9f-d0e7-4740-8ebe-0ce1d2e9ea7e  Rack1
UN  172.27.0.4  202.68 KB  256          ?       7a4b39bf-f38a-41ab-be33-c11a4e4e352c  Rack1
```

In the application, the Java driver I'm using is the DataStax Java driver 3.11.2.0 for Apache Cassandra. The way I connect with the DB is the following:

```
@Bean
    public Cluster cluster() {
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPointsWithPorts(
                        new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9042),
                        new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9043),
                        new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9044))
                .build();
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public Session session(Cluster cluster, @Value("${scylla.keyspace}") String keyspace) throws IOException {
        final Session session = cluster.connect();
        setupKeyspace(session, keyspace);
        return session;
    }
```

When running the application with the tomcat server, I receive a lot of connection errors at the start:

```
2022-07-19 22:42:38.424  WARN 28228 --- [r1-nio-worker-3] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection      : Error creating netty channel to /172.27.0.4:9042
```

However, after a small spam of log errors, the app eventually connects and its totally usable. I do have to wait for the node tool to execute and confirm that all nodes are up, though.

```
2022-07-19 23:25:12.324  INFO 25652 --- [  restartedMain] c.d.d.c.p.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy        : Using data-center name 'DC1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
2022-07-19 23:25:12.324  INFO 25652 --- [  restartedMain] com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host /172.27.0.3:9042 added
2022-07-19 23:25:12.324  INFO 25652 --- [  restartedMain] com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host /172.27.0.2:9042 added
2022-07-19 23:25:12.324  INFO 25652 --- [  restartedMain] com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9044 added
```

Then, I recently added "my-app" to my docker-compose file, but the app can't start and instantly shuts down even if I wait for the node status tool to confirm that all nodes are up.

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm connecting with the DB? I wonder why the embedded tomcat build works and the docker one instantly shuts down. I was hoping someone here could help me find a way for the docker-compose build to wait for all the scylla nodes to be up before starting my-app (I assume I can do it with a script in the dockerfile? Maybe?), but I can't even seem to start the app in docker the same way I did with the tomcat. Maybe I'm missing smething regarding the port and host when using docker.

Any ideas in what I could try to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Docker compose file edited with the app:

```
  my-app:
    container_name: my-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my-app
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    depends_on:
      - scylla-node1
      - scylla-node2
      - scylla-node3
    networks:
      - scylla-network
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use IP addresses in the contact points which are accessible from outside the containers, not `localhost`.

Typically, it will be the IP address you've configured for `CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS` (environment variable) or `rpc_address` (in your yaml).

If you didn't set the RPC addresses for the containers, you need to tell Cassandra what IP address to advertise to other nodes and clients by specifying a broadcast address with `CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS` or `broadcast_rpc_address`.

The important thing is that you need to use IP addresses which are reachable from your Spring Boot app. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick, thank you for the reply.

Indeed, I added --broadcast-rpc-address scylla-node1 command in the docker compose file for each respective node. After, I changed the contact points code and it worked! Thank you!

Though I do have another question. Is there a way for me to make the "my-app" only go up in docker when I have all the nodes ready? I mean, all of them with UN status with the node tool. Because what happens is that "my-app" fails to go up until the node status are all ok. Is there a way to make a script in the dockerfile to wait for this to happen?

Comment: That is really a separate question that is specific to Docker so best to create a new post. Cheers!